# How To add class to all table columns except first column in datatable

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables-1.10

Suppose Ajax Datatable where first Column contains record basic action and rest of the columns are record value. what i want is, I want to add class name say dummy to all the table columns except first.
Please Help.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Code meet the requirement

> columnDefs: [ 
>                 { className: "listViewRecordActions", orderable: false, "searchable": false, targets: [0] },
>                 { className: "listViewEntryValue", "targets": [ '_all' ] }          ],